# Insertar iframe el tiempo en mapa google

Tags: javascript, php, css

he insertado un mapa de google creado en mis sitios con la aplicación de google. Este mapa es una ventana pop-up que se abre cuando le doy a un boton y me ocupa el 100% de la pantalla. Lo que quiero ahora es añadirle un iframe que muestre el tiempo, pero no consigo que se muestre por pantalla sobre el mapa de google. En esta imagen explico visualmente lo que quiero conseguir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        
                        <div class="iframe_temperatura" style="position:absolute;right:50%;top:50%;">
                            <?php echo $video['weather'];?>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div id="mapa_google" class="code_<?php echo $count;?>">
                            <?php echo $video['code'];?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var url = $('.code_<?php echo $count;?> iframe').attr('src');
                    $('a.link_<?php echo $count;?>').attr('href', url);
                    </script>
```

```js
      /*  CBOX    */
    /////////////////////////
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:"group1", innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});
 $(".group2").colorbox({rel:"group2", transition:"fade", innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});
    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:"group3", transition:"fade", innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});
 $(".group4").colorbox({rel:"group4", slideshow:true});
 $(".ajax").colorbox();
 $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"100%", height:"100%"});
 $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
 $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});
 $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});

    
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var alto_pantalla = $(window).height();
            var ancho_pantalla = $(window).width();
            
            if( $('#cboxOverlay').css( 'visibility' ) ){
                $('.group1').colorbox.resize({ innerWidth:'100%',innerHeight:"100%" });
    $(".group2").colorbox.resize({ innerWidth:'100%',innerHeight:"100%" });
    $(".iframe").colorbox.resize({ innerWidth:'100%',innerHeight:"100%" });
    $(".inline").colorbox.resize({ innerWidth:'100%',innerHeight:"100%" });
            }
            
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Un iframe no te cargará por las restricciones de seguridad de Google.  Lo que puedes hacer es un div con una clase personalizada y manipularlo mediante Javascript para que se sobreponga.

Mediante css defines la clase o id y le asignas atributo z index para ponerlo delante.

Comment: manipularlo en java script cómo? la verdad es que no manejo mucho java script, me podrias poner un ejemplo? Llevo mucho tiempo intentando hacer esto y no consigo sacarlo